# How can I study the convergence of the following sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Let we have the following sequence in $L^2$
The sequence is $$X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,......,x_n,......)$$
Such that 
$$x_1=(1,0,0,0,0,0,,.....)$$
$$x_2=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,0,0,,...)$$
$$x_3=(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,0,.....)$$
$$............$$
$$x_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},.....,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,0,,....)$$
I mean in any ($x_n$) we repeat  the fraction ($\frac{1}{n}$) in the sequence ( $n^2$ )times .
Now how can I study the convergence of this sequence $X$ in $L^2$ space

Comment: Please, do not make [substantial changes to the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1167798/revisions), especially in the case tha you already have an answer. (If you need to you can ask new question.) About books for FA - you should be able to find some suggestions if you browse questions tagged [unctional-analysis+book-recommendation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis+book-recommendation) and [functional-analysis+reference-request](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis+reference-request).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: The sequence does not converge. The only possible candidate to which it could converge is the all-$0$ sequence (because if it converges, it converges in each coordinate, and by coordinates, it converges to $0$), but the norm of the elements clearly does not converge toward $0$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a converging sequence in $\ell^2$. Coordinate-wise, we have convergence towards zero, but for every $i$ we have $\| x_i \|_2 = 1$.